# Script terminated by timeout at:

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
let ring = 0

 while (ring < 10) {

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.key == "q") {
            console.log(fight.punch(console.log(fight.health)))
            document.getElementById('kicked').play()
            ring += 1
        }
        else if (e.key == "a") {
            console.log(fight.kick(console.log(fight.health)))
            document.getElementById('fastpunch').play()
            ring += 1
        }
        else if (e.key == "p") {
            console.log("that the shit")
            document.getElementById('kicked').play()
        }
        else if (e.key == "l") {
            console.log("that the shit")
            document.getElementById('fastpunch').play()
        }
    })
}
```

i am trying to play audio but my code is not working in fact my browser is giving me a error i will try every thing but nothing happened

Comment: Why are they in a while loop?

Comment: _“The [`addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method […] sets up a function that will be called whenever the specified event is delivered to the target.”_ — You’re setting up infinitely many functions, none of which can ever be called because the main processed is blocked by the infinite loop. There is nothing that needs to be looped here. It looks like you need to remove the `while` loop, and put an `if(ring < 10)` inside the event listener.

Comment: First thing you need is to get rid of the `while` loop or at least add a `ring += 1;` right before its closing `}`. Otherwise, as stated in the previous comment, the loop never ends.

Comment: @evolutionxbox  because i need to stop the function then the work is done thats why i am using function and please suggest me the better way to do this

Comment: @acdcjunior i don't understand properly can you please explain me properly

Comment: Let me rephrase it: What's the purpose of the `ring` variable?